# Kibana and elastic compatibility issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I started using elastic search v7.17.2 and kibana v8.1.2 on mac os monterey 12.3.1

[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] This version of Kibana (v8.1.2) is incompatible with the following Elasticsearch nodes in your cluster: v7.17.2 @ 127.0.0.1:9200 (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Upgrade your Elasticsearch

Comment: installed latest verison of elastic search but i am not able to access localhost:9200 It shows  "received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200" in terminal

Comment: @Gajendar Open your config/elasticsearch.yml file  and update these flags.

xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade version of elastic search to 8.1.2, Make sure your elastic version(major and minor) are same, then it will solve the problem